# ASP.NET MVC Web Application connecting to WCF web service errors with large data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, xml-deserialization

**EDIT**

I am using MVC 3 trying to call a method in a WCF service that the MVC service has consumed and get the following error when I call the method.

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:emailData. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type EmailPO. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 89, position 1075.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

This is not just related to ASP.NET as I thought. I have a WPF Application that also uses this service that locally works with Cassini. When I use an identical WPF application and consume the service after publishing this same WCF service, I also get the above error running teh same method.

**ASP.NET MVC Client Web.config that does not work:**

```
    <configSections>    
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
          <section name="UserInterface.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>
      <!--<location path="~/Content/images" allowOverride="false">
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
          </authorization>      
        </system.web>
      </location>-->
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Configuration" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
                     allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" 
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="102400" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>

          <endpoint address="http://server1/WebServices/MasterEngine/MasterEngineService.svc?wsdl" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Configuration" contract="MasterEngineFarEnd.IMasterEngineService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" />
         --- Later on after company specific stuff --
<system.web>    
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="5120" executionTimeout="1200" />    
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />        
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>        
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>-->
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Routing" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

**WCF Service (MasterEngine) Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Configuration" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="1073741824" maxArrayLength="102400"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>

        <!-- OLD CONFIG 
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Configuration" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
         openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        -->
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>

           <endpoint address="http://server2/WebServices/InternalService/InternalService.svc"
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Configuration"
             contract="InternalFarEnd.IInternalService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IInternalHubService" />

    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>


  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**WPF application that does not work**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>

      <diagnostics>
        <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true"
          messageFlowTracing="true" />
      </diagnostics>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Configuration" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="1073741824" maxStringContentLength="1073741824"
                        maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxBytesPerRead="1073741824" maxNameTableCharCount="1073741824" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://server01-dev/WebServices/MasterEngine/MasterEngineService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Configuration"
                contract="MasterEngineFarEnd.IMasterEngineService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**WPF application that does work**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>

      <diagnostics>
        <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true"
          messageFlowTracing="true" />
      </diagnostics>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Configuration" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="1073741824" maxStringContentLength="1073741824"
                        maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxBytesPerRead="1073741824" maxNameTableCharCount="1073741824" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://server01-dev/WebServices/MasterEngine/MasterEngineService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Configuration"
                contract="MasterEngineFarEnd.IMasterEngineService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have gone through adding the max-everything as other threads have said along with what the error actually states, but I see no where at this point where  8192 even applies or what it could be referring to. If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. if needed, my class that it is referring to looks like this.. with the DataMembers / DataContracts set up

**Email PO Class**

```
[DataContract]
    public class EmailPO
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string FromEmail { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<String> ToEmail { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<String> CcEmail { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string FullHTML { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<EmailClassLibrary.AttachmentItem> Attachments { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string TableHeader { get; set; }


    }
```

**EDIT - UPDATE**

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>


<endpoint address="http://server1/WebServices/MasterEngine/MasterEngineService.svc?wsdl"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Configuration"
                contract="MasterEngineFarEnd.IMasterEngineService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService"/>
```

Also Tried it with giving it a name and updating the endpoint to use the same name for behaviorConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Its an Issue where the serialization graph of our objects exceeded the default max limits.
So in Service config add this line.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
   ...
  <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    ...
  </system.serviceModel>
```

It is works for me in WCF service config.

EDIT: you can refer this link [CLICK here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2010/05/04/setting-maxitemsinobjectgraph-for-wcf-there-has-to-be-a-better-way.aspx)

Comment: this did not fix the issue. See edit above.. Same Error displayed